# error for drupal 6 local

Tags: php, drupal, localhost, local

This error appears when I finished the setup of local site

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\cities\includes\theme.inc on line 92

why??

what the solution ????????

Answer (score 0):

That means that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: What file do you mean? The function in question is _init_theme and the line of code is $theme_path = dirname($theme->filename); and likely $theme is not initalized but I am at a loss to figure out why.